# undefined is showing up in options

Tags: javascript

In JS

```
var vehicleData = [{year: 2015, make: "Audi", model: "A4"},
{year: 2014, make: "Benz", model: "c2000"},
{year: 2015, make: "Maruti", model: "s-cross"},
{year: 2015, make: "Maruti", model: "WagonR"}
];
var uniqueNames=[];

for(var i = 0; i<vehicleData.length; i++){
buildDropdownYear(i);
}

function buildDropdownYear(n) {
var yearSelect = document.getElementById("selectMe");
var drop1 = document.createElement("option");
var carYear = buildCtrl(n, uniqueNames,"option");
yearSelect.appendChild(carYear);
}

function buildCtrl(n, data, ctrl){
for(var i = 0; i< vehicleData.length; i++){
if(uniqueNames.indexOf(vehicleData[i].year) === -1){
    uniqueNames.push(vehicleData[i].year);        
}
}
 for(i = 0; i< uniqueNames.length; i++){    
console.log(uniqueNames[i]);      
}

var item = document.createElement(ctrl);
if(data){
    item.innerHTML = data[n];
}
return item;
}
```

After output, undefined is coming in dropdown. I want unique values in dropdown from year section [from json data].

My plunker code is: http://plnkr.co/edit/fMufqCctzHe4Umbpu6Ag?p=preview

Comment: did any of the answers work for you? you should mark one as correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here, that are only going to get worse once you start making the other dropdown menus, you should always look to abstract away as much as possible, so you can use your function(s) over and over:

This does what you want in one function:  [NEW PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/e9GBnvePLADCRUCGdRUK?p=preview)

```
var vehicleData = [{year: 2015, make: "Audi", model: "A4"},
    {year: 2014, make: "Benz", model: "c2000"},
    {year: 2016, make: "Maruti", model: "s-cross"},
    {year: 2015, make: "Maruti", model: "WagonR"}
];

function buildDD(id){
  var selector = document.getElementById(id);

  var newDataArray = vehicleData.map(function(d) {
    return d[id]
  })
  var uniques = newDataArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (a.indexOf(b) === -1) {
      a.push(b);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);

  uniques.forEach(function(el) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = el;

    selector.appendChild(opt)
  })
  return newDataArray;
}

buildDD('year')
buildDD('make')
buildDD('model')
```